# Is there anything in AI field such as lambda-the-ultimate in PL field?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is there any weblog or forums or discussion groups in artificial intelligence field such as the [lambda-the-ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/) in programming language field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Geoffrey says, most blogs or forums or discussion groups are fragmented. Here are below a couple of websites.

http://ai-faq.com/#BestPlacesToTalkAboutAI:

- OR Exchange (Operation research)
- GameDev.net (Game AI)
- AIGameDev (Game AI)
- Developpez.com (wide AI but in French)

http://ai-faq.com/#otherFAQs:

- comp.ai.neural-nets
- comp.ai.nat-lang: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/natural-lang-processing-faq/
- comp.ai.genetic: ftp://rtfm.mit.edu/pub/usenet/comp.ai.genetic/
- comp.lang.lisp: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/Groups/AI/lang/lisp/faq/

http://ai-faq.com/#AIclasses:

- a series of recent online classes: http://www.class-central.com/
- Berkeley Webcast
- MIT OpenCourseWare as well as MITx / edX soon
- Stanford Engineering Everywhere (SEE)
- Miscellaneous AI lectures: http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/Artificial_Intelligence/

Comment: That's a good collection (although I wouldn't add a programming language as lisp under AI). Another good resource is [AI class](https://www.ai-class.com).

Comment: thanks! good idea, I could add a few AI classes: http://ai-faq.com/#AIclasses (the best one for introduction into the field being probably the one you said)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any overall AI blog like that. AI is a very broad topic: most blogs just cover a subsection. Here's our blog that covers a range of AI topics (not all of them), but it's focused on a single, practical implementation (so maybe not what you're looking for):

- [All things Artificial Intelligence related: Rules, Processes, Events, Agents, Planning, Ontologies and more: Drools & jBPM team blog](http://blog.athico.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a few blogs about Machine Learning:

- [This Number Crunching Life](http://blog.smellthedata.com/)
- [ML Theory](http://hunch.net/)
- [Data Mining: Text Mining, Visualization and Social Media](http://datamining.typepad.com/data_mining/)
- [AI and Social Science](http://brenocon.com/blog/)